# Is there a single word that can describe the phrase "in their view"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When talking about a concept that someone else thinks is correct, but I as the writer am skeptical about, is there a word that can summarise that feeling?

> The woman was fighting for justice.

But I don't necessarily agree that what she's fighting for is just.

So you'd think the solution would be

> The woman was fighting for what in her view was just.

But I want to take a more neutral stance, and that sentence sounds confrontational, as if I DISAGREE with what she's saying.

I'm looking for something that looks a bit like "the woman was fighting for her justice" maybe I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ***allegedly***, which is often used to distance oneself from whatever is being claimed:

> *allegedly*
> reportedly; supposedly; an exclamation expressing disbelief or scepticism ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/allegedly))

There is a usage note in Collins which states that:

> it is also possible to use *allegedly* as an expression of ironic scepticism:
>
> - He's a hard worker. Allegedly.

Answer (score 0):

"...I don't necessarily agree that what she's fighting for is just."

> The woman **would say** she's fighting for justice.

By using the conditional *would,* you state what she is doing in her view, but make it clear that you or others may have different views. If you use a verb like *claims* or *maintains*, you imply there is evidence, e.g., statements that she has made about her motive, whereas "would say" implies you are just intuiting how she sees it.

If you use *would,* you could replace *say* with a stronger verb like *claim* or *maintain* if it were more appropriate.

> The woman **would claim** she's fighting for justice.

Answer (score 0):

This word seems to  fit the bill nicely: **Supposedly**

> according to what is generally assumed or believed (often used to indicate that the speaker doubts the truth of the statement).

*there were rumours of a rift between him and his colleagues, supposedly because they were jealous of his relationship with the Duchess.*

*Traffic numbers have supposedly been monitored, but does anyone really know what it is like?*

[Lexico]

Comment: I consider this worse than “in her view” in terms of suggestion of disbelief

Comment: @David OP said he wants to "take a neutral stand", and I thought _supposedly_ captured that sentiment nicely.

Comment: As my answer explains, I associate the term with a prosecuting lawyer, e.g. “But the witness was supposedly too absorbed in his newspaper to…”

Answer (score 0):

I would contest the premise that “in her view” implies disbelief on the part of the writer. I think it much less suggestive of this than the suggestions “supposedly” or “allegedly” because these might well be used to suggest disbelief in courts of law.

Perhaps even more neutral than “view” is a sentence where the idea is delegated to the verb “consider”:

> The woman was fighting for what she **considered to be** justice.

The reason I regard this as more neutral than, e.g. “believed/thought” etc. Is that consideration implies more thoughtful reflection than “belief”.

However, this has a cultural element and is rather subjective.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. of which some have already been suggested by fev, by user 405662 and DjinTonic.

Another possibility is the use of what have been known as 'scare quotes', or even 'sneer quotes'.  So

> the woman was fighting for 'justice' (or 'fighting for justice'.

This use of inverted commas holds the statement at a distance from the speaker.

Or you can Use a scepticism main verb:-

> The woman imagined herself to be fighting for justice.

Or

> The woman imagined she was fighting for justice.

Answer (score 0):

> They felt they were fighting for justice.

With this approach, the narrator acknowledges that the fighter felt strongly about what they consider just and what they considered unjust, but the narrator maintains a neutral stance.

Alternatively:

> They were fighting for their view / version of *justice*.

Answer (score 0):

**Subjective**

> The woman was fighting for her **subjective** view *of justice*.

OED

> **Subjective: (adj.) 4.a. Of, relating to, or proceeding from an individual's thoughts, views, etc.; derived from or expressing a person's individuality or idiosyncrasy; *not impartial or literal; personal, individual.***
>
> 1858   O. W. Holmes Autocrat of Breakfast-table xi. 311   The
> ingenuous reader will understand that this was an internal, private,
> personal, subjective diorama.
>
> a1871   G. Grote Fragm. Ethical Subj. (1876) ii. 42   This sentiment is..a subjective sentiment—that is, each individual experiences it in a degree and manner peculiar to himself.
>
> 1964   Listener 24 Dec. 1002/1   Jean-Paul Sartre,..makes of his
> subjective and personal passions a sort of objective truth.

Comment: Or "subjectively fighting for justice".